# Having trouble installing bndTools with Gradle?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, bndtools

I have Gradlev2.9 installed. I also have bndTools downloaded from https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools. I am running on a closed network so no Interwebs. I deleted the Ivy repository since we dont have Ivy, its in the  settings.gradle file under repository{}. I also commented out the attempted connection in gradle.properties file.

Also, I attempted to put the missing jar files directly into the root bndTools folder and gradle still didnt pick them up.

Am I missing something...?

C:\Program Files\bndTools\bndtools-master>gradle -v

---

### Gradle 2.9

Build time:   2015-11-17 07:02:17 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b463d7980c40d44c4657dc80025275b84a29e31f

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_31 (Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07)

### OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64

C:\Program Files\bndTools\bndtools-master>

My Error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Settings file 'C:\Program Files\bndTools\bndtools-master\settings.gradle' line: 28
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating settings 'bndtools-master'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
>     Cannot resolve external dependency biz.aQute.bnd:biz.aQute.bnd.gradle:latest because no repositories are defined.
>      Required by:
>          unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1.482 secs

Thanks!